# Ошибка при определении функции xor

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
bool xor(bool a,bool b);   
int main ()

{
    bool p,q;
    cout<<"vvedite P (0 ili 1): ";
    cin>>p;
    cout<<"vvedite Q (0 ili 1): ";
    cin>>q;
    cout<<"P i Q: "<<(p&&q)<<' \n';
    cout<<"P ili Q: "<<(p||q)<<' \n';
    cout<<"P xor Q: "<<xor(p,q)<<' \n';
    return 0;
}

bool xor(bool a,bool b)
{
    return (a||b)&&!(a&&b);
}
```

ругается на месте bool xor

Answer (score 6):

`xor` - это альтернативная лексема (см. [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative#Alternative_tokens)). Они нужны на системах с ограниченным набором символов, например где нет символа `^` или `&`.

Эта лексема будет рассматриваться как оператор `^`. Следовательно объявление функции будет рассматриваться как `bool ^(bool a, bool b)`;

Замените имя `xor` на другое, например `my_xor` - и все заработает.

Comment: благадарю. все заработало.